# Reposition Air NativeWindow when Maximized?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3

How can I set the native window position when maximized?

I've tried repositioning it upon the DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGE event which sort of works - but the window flashes at maximized size before repositioning, and more importantly the 'maximize' button of the window is still active.

What I'm trying to achieve is simply a fixed width window that is 'docked' to the right of the screen when maximized while still utilizing the restore/maximize native window button functionality.

I should note that I have set the maxSize and minSize and that is working fine.

Thanks in advance - b

Comment: Is this question too difficult, or have I somehow mis-tagged it and left it orphaned to never be addressed?

Comment: Try posting updates on new things you have tried in your question, as this makes it go to the front page again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent.DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGING